# Proper translation for “The Love Boat”

Tags: traduction, anglais, noms-propres

Would you say Le Bateau D'Amour or Le Bateau de L'Amour to translate from the English "The Love Boat?"

Comment: D'amour. Usually when qualifying the type of a thing it's just de + type.

Comment: Je suis pas vraiment d'accord avec toi @LukeSawczak, pour moi *bateau d'amour* a plus le sens de *un charmant bateau* (quelque chose du style *lovely boat*)  apres je dis ça en tant que Français, c'est peut être autrement dans les autres pays de la francophonie ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm trying to decide what would be best as the name of a large boat (53' Hatteras).

Comment: @Flying Hmm, that is a fair point about the overlap with "lovely".

Comment: See also [_vaisseau_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vaisseau). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't capitalize the same way you do in English so that would be:

> *Le Bateau d'amour.*
>
> *Le Bateau de l'amour.*

I would hesitate using either names for being a little cheesy and even possibly ambiguous so my suggestion would be :

> *Un amour de bateau.*

Note that the TV series *The love boat* was translated in French *La croisière s'amuse* (literally: "The cruise has fun"), so that might be a funny choice too.

Answer (score 0):

Histoire d'amour = love story

Chanson d'amour = love song

Bateau d'amour = love boat

*but*

Ville de l'amour (Paris) = city of Love